# Not able to print the XML Response from a SOAP webservice

Tags: java, wsdl, code-generation, apache-axis

I am not able to print the response from a Soap Webservice.

Seen few solutions by editing the generated stub code. But I cant edit the generated code as it gets restored to original form on every build. Looking for a solution where I can get the solution printed without change in generated code.

I am consuming the SOAP service from a Spring Boot microservice.

```java
ServiceContext serviceConxt = omsSchedulingService._getServiceClient().getServiceContext();
        OperationContext operationContext = serviceConxt.getLastOperationContext();
MessageContext inMessageContext = operationContext.getMessageContext("Out");
log.info(inMessageContext.getEnvelope().toString());
```

Comment: How is this related to the tool [tag:soapui]?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a message handler for the soap message.

Then once you intercept the message with the handler, you can print out the response.

You will need to add the handler to the handler chain, depending on your project you can do that programatically or with config.

```
final class MyMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{


@Override
public void close(MessageContext context) {
    handle(context);
}

private boolean handle(MessageContext context) {
    if (context != null) {
        try {
            Object httpResponseCodeObj = context.get(SOAPMessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE);

            if (httpResponseCodeObj instanceof Integer)
                httpResponseCode = ((Integer) httpResponseCodeObj).intValue();

            if (context instanceof SOAPMessageContext) {
                SOAPMessage message = ((SOAPMessageContext) context).getMessage();
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(512);
                message.writeTo(byteOut);
                String messageStr = byteOut.toString(getCharacterEncoding(message));

                boolean outbound = Boolean.TRUE.equals(context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY));


                Logger.info(loggingPrefix, outbound ? "SOAP request: " : "SOAP response: ", replaceNewLines(messageStr));
            }

        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            Logger.error(e, loggingPrefix, "SOAPException: ", e.getMessage(), NEWLINE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.error(e, loggingPrefix, "IOException: ", e.getMessage(), NEWLINE);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: I have seen this answer  before.But this wont work for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to implement an interceptor the easiest way is to use the logging via vm arguments:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire=debug -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=debug
```

This way you should see the logging of your request / response with headers in console.

Answer (score 0):

First you can get AxisConfiguration from client stub.

```
AxisConfiguration axisConf = stub._getServiceClient().getAxisConfiguration();
```

Processing incoming and outgoing messages is divided into phases. There is a list of phases (a flow) which is processed when everything works correctly (without errors) and also another for situations when some fault occurs e.g. when an exception is thrown during message processing. Every flow maybe incoming or outgoing so there are 4 flows altogether.

```
List<Phase> phasesIn = axisConf.getInFlowPhases(); // normal incoming communication i.e. response from webservice
List<Phase> phasesOut = axisConf.getOutFlowPhases(); // normal outgoing communication
List<Phase> phasesFaultIn = axisConf.getInFaultFlowPhases(); // faulty incoming communication e.g. when an exception occurs during message processing
List<Phase> phasesFaultOut = axisConf.getOutFaultFlowPhases(); // faulty outgoing communication
```

Some but not all phase names are defined in org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver.PhaseMetadata.
For example "Security" phase processed in Rampart module (module for Web Service Security) won't be found in PhaseMetadata.
You can add a handler to every phase, e.g.

```
for (Phase p : phasesOut) {
    if (PhaseMetadata.PHASE_TRANSPORT_OUT.equals(p.getName())) {
        p.addHandler(new MessageContentLoggerHandler());
    }
}
```

Handler is a class which extends org.apache.axis2.handlers.AbstractHandler.
You just have to implement

```
public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext msgContext).
```

There you have access to MessageContext. Of course, you can get whole SOAP envelope like this:

```
msgContext.getEnvelope().toString()
```

and for example print it to your logs or save as a separate file.
Remember to put

```
return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
```

at the end of invoke method for a situation when handler processes the message successfully. Otherwise processing stops in this handler and a whole process won't get to any another phase.
If you need to see whole message with WSS headers, you can add your own phase. For example this adds your custom phase as the last in processing of outgoing message (so also after Rampart's security phase)

```
Phase phase = new Phase("SomePhase");
phase.addHandler(new SomeCustomHandler());
axisConf.getOutFlowPhases().add(phase);
```

Of course logging (and exposing in any other way) security headers in production environment is a very bad idea. Do it only for debugging purposes in some test environment.